# How to get momentum-based scrolling for the the root <html> element working on iOS Safari?

Tags: javascript, css, mobile-safari

We've run into a problem getting **momentum-based scrolling** to work on iOS Safari for the **root `<html>` element**.

The following does get the desired results:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

However, the scrollbar completely disappears from the screen.

Tried the following suggestion to get back the scrollbar, but doesn't work.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 7px;
}
```

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}

This doesn't work either:

```
body {
    height: calc(100% + 1px);
}
```

When I say the scrollbar disappears I mean the scrollbar just does not exist. The following JS prints '0', even when scrolled half-way down the page:

```
const y = document.body.scrollTop || 
document.documentElement.scrollTop || 
document.scrollingElement.scrollTop;
```

console.log(y);

I'm aware that momentum-based scrolling on iOS Safari is buggy.

- Has anyone managed to get scrolling working for the root `<html>` element?
- Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get the scroll value `document.body.scrollTop`?

We're currently not looking to use any external libraries.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS property and try again.

```css
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-overflow-scrolling